# How to close a child case automatically when a parent case is closed in CommCare

Tags: commcare

Is is possible to automatically close the child cases associated with a parent case when the parent case closes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project space as a Pro Plan or higher, you can now auto close the child case based on the parent case closure. It is now part of the standard drop-down options when you create an automatic case closure rule per the documentation found [here](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Automatically+Update+Cases).

Answer (score 2):

It actually is possible to set up automatic child case closure based on the parent case closing, it just takes a few steps, and isn't exactly immediate:

1) when closing the parent case, set the case property close_case = 'yes'

2) go to the Data tab > [automatically close cases](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Automatically+Close+Cases), and set a new rule for the child case type with the filter parent/case_close = yes. You will have to specify the # of days after which the case should close if it hasn't been updated. Select the minimum (which I believe is 30). This means that when the parent case closes, the child case will close 30 days later.

3) to make sure these cases don't appear in your case lists, set the case list filter parent/close_case != 'yes' and/or close_case != 'yes' depending on the case type of the module.

It's a bit of a work around, but in the eye of the user, those cases will be gone as soon as the parent is closed, and on the back end, they'll be closed in 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to update child cases or their properties from a parent case module, so you're correct, it isn't possible to close them either.
You will instead need to close them with a form in a module of the child case-type.

Here are some options that I've used for different workflows.  None are perfect, but may work in your use case.

1. Don't allow the parent to be closed if it has any children.  For instance, don't let a household case be closed until after all members are closed.
2. Always use parent-child selection such that any child cases that are left open with closed parents cannot be seen by the user.  Then use an automatic case closure rule to clean up the child cases after some period of time.
3. Have a case list that only shows child cases whose parents are closed.  Train the users to periodically go there to clean it out.